# Fetching data from the internet in Java

Tags: java, dom, jsoup

Good day, I am new to Java and I am trying to catch some data from the internet. If I want to for an example to search google and store the number of results and the search time.
I thought about using jsoup DOM features, but I cant figure out how to get the value of that specific element.

If I use google chrome to inspect element the bit I'm interested in is

```
<div id="resultStats">
About 6,480,000,000 results
<nobr>  (0.26 seconds)&nbsp;</nobr>
</div>
```

Thats the only thing I can get to work, but the Document does not include that element.

```
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;


import java.io.IOException;

public class google_time {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String url = "https://www.google.com/webhp?hl=en&tab=Tw&q=data#hl=en&newwindow=1&output=search&sclient=psy-ab&q=data&oq=data&gs_l=hp.12...0.0.0.1682.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0..0.0.les%3B..0.0...1c.Q9UUbwkFy-I&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&fp=6a12f0870d3ff179&biw=1066&bih=483";

        Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
        System.out.println(doc);

    }
}
```

So how do I get only that bit resultStatic and the text in there ?

Comment: jsoup provides DOM (Document Object Model) which you can navigate, try having a read through the [examples here](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/dom-navigation)

Comment: Also have a look at [this](https://norrisshelton.wordpress.com/2011/01/27/jsoup-java-html-parser/), in particular the section on `jquery` and [examples](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax)

Answer (score 1):

First the problem:

Looks like url `https://www.google.com/webhp` is used for dynamic rendering of google search page. ie using AJAX to fetch search result and then render it into the page using javascript. Since `jsoup` is not a browser and doesn't run javascript, the html you'll get using `jsoup` will not have any search result.

So instead we could use `https://www.google.com/search`. This would render a normal html page with result without any AJAX hooplah. But google still blocks requests from non-browser sources so you'd have to add `UserAgent` header to your `Jsoup` request like this:

```
Jsoup.connect(url)
    .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; WindowsNT 5.1;"+
        " en-US; rv1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070725 Firefox/2.0.0.6")
    .get();
```

And your final code would look something like this:

```
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.io.IOException;

public class GoogleScraper {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String url = "https://www.google.com/search?"+
        "hl=en&tab=Tw&q=data#hl=en&newwindow=1&"+
        "output=search&sclient=psy-ab&q=data&oq=data"+
        "&gs_l=hp.12...0.0.0.1682.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0..0.0.les"+
        "%3B..0.0...1c.Q9UUbwkFy-I&pbx=1&bav=on.2,"+
        "or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&fp=6a12f0870d3ff179&biw=1066&bih=483";

        try{

            Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url)
            .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; WindowsNT 5.1;"+
                " en-US; rv1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070725 Firefox/2.0.0.6")
            .get();

            //Prints the whole markup
            //System.out.println(doc.toString());

            Elements resultDivElems = doc.select("div#resultStats");
            Iterator<Element> itr = resultDivElems.iterator();

            //Prints only what you need, ie the result details
            while(itr.hasNext()){
                System.out.println(((Element)itr.next()).text());
            }
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks but this did not work, also you have to use Elements not Element, but still no success